# Finding derivatives without limits/difference quotients

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, recreational-mathematics, lambert-w

The goal here is to find the derivative of $f(x)$, where $f(x)$ is a non-linear continuous function.

Let $y_1=f(x)$ and $y_2=ax+b$, such that we will find $y_2$ to be the tangent line at $x=c$.

Set $y_1=y_2$ and solve for $x$

$$f(x)=ax+b$$

$$x=x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots,x_n$$

Find $x_p$ and $x_q$ such that $x_p$ and $x_q$ are the closest to $x=c$ where $x_p\le c\le x_q$.

Set $x_p=x_q(=c$ by squeezey theorem$)$, so that we have

$$c=x_{p,q}$$

where $x_p$ and $x_q$ are given in terms of $a,b$.  Solve for $a$ to get

$$a=g(c)$$

which we will rewrite as

$$a(c)=g(c)$$

Finally, we have

$$\frac d{dx}f(x)=a(x)$$

---

Example,

$$y_1=x^2,\ y_2=ax+b$$

$$x^2=ax+b$$

$$x^2-ax-b=0$$

$$x_p=\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2+4b}}2=\ x_q=\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2+4b}}2$$

Set $c=x_p=x_q$

$$c=\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2+4b}}2=\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2+4b}}2$$

Solving the right side, we get

$$a^2+4b=0$$

So we have

$$c=\frac a2\implies a(c)=2c$$

So finally,

> $$\frac d{dx}x^2=a(x)=2x$$

---

Another example,

$$y_1=\frac1x,\ y_2=ax+b$$

$$\frac1x=ax+b\implies ax^2+bx-1=0$$

$$x_p=\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2+4a}}{2a},\ x_q=\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2+4a}}{2a}$$

Set $c=x_p=x_q$

$$c=\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2+4a}}{2a}=\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2+4a}}{2a}$$

Solving the right side gives

$$b^2+4a=0\implies b^2=-4a$$

$$c=\frac{-b}{2a}$$

$$c^2=\frac{b^2}{4a^2}=\frac{-4a}{4a^2}=\frac{-1}a$$

$$a(c)=\frac{-1}{c^2}$$

> $$\frac d{dx}\frac1x=a(x)=\frac{-1}{x^2}$$

---

And lastly, another example that highlights we do not actually have to solve for $x$,

$$y_1=x^3,\ y_2=ax+b$$

$$x^3=ax+b\implies x^3-ax-b=0$$

Two roots will be $c$, and one root will be $x_r$, so we have

$$\begin{align}x^3-ax-b&=(x-x_r)(x-c)^2\\&=x^3-(2c+x_r)x^2+(c^2+2x_rc)x-c^2r\end{align}$$

By equating parts, we have

$$2c+x_r=0,\ c^2+2x_rc=-a$$

$$x_r=-2c$$

$$c^2+2(-2c)c=c^2-4c^2=-3c^2=-a$$

$$a(c)=3c^2$$

> $$\frac d{dx}x^3=a(x)=3x^2$$

---

I've done this for $\sqrt{x}$ and other polynomials, and in all cases, this method has worked out.

---

So, to what extent does this method work?  Can it solve higher degree polynomial derivatives?  Can someone derive power rule and other similar derivative rules?  Can we take derivatives of transcendental functions using this?

As an example, can I use this to differentiate $e^x$?  Indeed, it is possible to solve for $x$ in $e^x=ax+b$, but how do I separate the solutions?  How can I make that work?

---

Has someone else found this?  It seems pretty basic when you visualize what this all means, though apparently this wasn't very popular if someone discovered this a long time ago.

Comment: This is too long to read, but you are saying that slope of tangent is derivative at that point, right? If so, this is a [known fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent#More_rigorous_description) and is very much the motivation for the limit definition.

Comment: @Ennar Yes, but it usually isn't used to find the derivative of the whole function, and as far as I've heard, people don't do it this way.

Comment: Well, no, it's usually the other way around, you find tangent lines with derivatives. This will always work, but you can't generally find tangent line without calculus. Your examples are algebraic, so algebraic tools work, but what about other examples? I have no clue how you would find tangent in general.

Comment: @Ennar and that is one of my questions.  And if we find tangential lines with derivatives, how do we define derivatives?  With limits and secant lines?  The goal is to skip limits and secants all together and attempt pure algebra.

Comment: Well, if you have polynomial $f(x)$, then $ax+b$ is tangent iff $f(x) - (ax+b)$ has a multiple root. You can argue similarly for rational functions. Beyond that you leave the domain of algebra.

Comment: Try the same for $f(x) = e^x$...

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Yes, and then we get Lambert W function.